# NOClassdefError found "com.firebase.client.Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using a Android device to send data to a Firebase backend. I receive the error NOClassdefError  found  "com.firebase.client.Firebase.

I have read the posts about "importing the firebase jar files"

I am using Eclipse-Luna and Android 23.03

I can import google play without a problem - but not the firebase client.

I'm lost(tried the switch over for src and gen - didn't work for me)